# How to show a module in Joomla when it's not a Menu item

Tags: joomla

I am trying to show a module, but the article I want to show the module on is not linked to a menu item. Is this possible? Seems like a module can only show when it is a menu item. But I have a ton of articles that are not menu items - so what is easiest way to show the module? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your article is under a category which is linked to a menu then they should show. 
If they are uncategorized then they will need to be linked directly to menu.

If you don't want the category to show on the menu....then link it to a menu your not using...the article should then show - of course for anybody to find it this way their should be a link from some other part of your site or externally

Comment: lol this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Do you want to show the module in a standard module position? Also, is this super specific i.e. only this one page or is it possible you want to show this module elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is as follows.

Let's suppose you have a group of articles that you wish to all display the same modules on.

1. Create a new category using the "category manager" option from the content menu
2. Ensure all the articles are published into this same category.
3. Create a new menu which you won't actually ever display anywhere (I like to publish the menu into a module position which is not present in the template)
4. Add a category blog layout option to this new menu
5. Now go through each of the modules that you wish to display for the group and add them to the new menu item you have created.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This will be my first answer after getting so many help through stackoverflow without being a member.
I will just add something to buzzki's answer. Because i was almost loosing my mind until i figure out how to solve.

If you used an article in a module with an extension like mod_articleasmodule; it adds the aliases of articles on URL of Read More.
Simply change the line;

`$link = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=".$item->id.":".$item->alias."&catid=".$item->catid.":".$item->catalias;`

to

`$link = "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=".$item->id."&catid=".$item->catid;`

to get the pure URL Link and your menu assigned by MetaMod will work. Also great thanks to buzzki for help.

Answer (score 1):

While the {loadposition xxx} technique is very handy, what it won't do is to put the module into any of the "standard" module positions (e.g. left, right, banner, or whatever your template has).

If you want your module in one of those positions, a great method is to use [MetaMod](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/3391). MetaMod is a placeholder module, that includes other modules inside of itself according to rules that you set up.

So you can set it up with a rule that says, in effect, "if we are on article A, B, C, D or E, display the module".

```
if ($content_genius->check("article_id = 50, 51, 52, 53, 54")) return XXX;
// replace XXX with the module id to show on those articles
```

Now, if the number of articles is going to change regularly, you don't want to have to edit the MetaMod to change the list of ids. So another way is to use the Meta Keywords field in the articles to determine whether the module will appear. Then all you have to do is include that keyword on any article you want the module to appear on. Let's say the keyword will be "SHOWMOD".

So in MetaMod you can simply use this:

```
if ($content_genius->check("article_metakeywords contains SHOWMOD")) return XXX;
// replace XXX with the module id to show on those articles
```

In that way, the module will appear on every article page where the article contains that meta keyword. And the module position can be any position on the page (wherever the MetaMod is assigned).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: On the front end of your website, click to the specific article that you want, highlight and copy the URL.

Step 2: Create a menu item, item type is URL and paste your article URL in there.  (You can have the menu item be in an unpublished menu i think)

Step 3: Select it from the Menu Items list in the module.

Answer (score 0):

You simply name your module position whatever you want, say 'monkey' where your module offers a 'select position'. You actually type it in. Then in the article you want to place it in, you add

```
{loadposition monkey}
```

to any location of your article you want the mod to work in the html editor.

Comment: This really is the easiest way, as it is 2 steps, little code and can be very customizable. Some modules might require the other way Matti has done though, depending on the type of module.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps in your joomla site Admin panel:

1. Go to the module manager, open the desired module and give a unique name in the position field. If you want to use it also at other common position such as left or right, then first create a copy of this module and then for the new copy, create a unique position name. Example: custom1.
2. Create a new article preferably uncategorized. Give it the name of your module.
3. In the body area of the article type {loadposition custom1} and save your article.
4. Create a Menu link to this article in the desired menu. You should select 'Article layout.'

Thats all, your module will now load from the menu link directly.

This has an added advantage of giving you SEO prominance based on the meta info you give for this article.